# Capture characters before and after matching term

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I'm writing a Ruby script that searches text files for the names of cities and towns in Massachusetts. I need to capture a certain number of characters surrounding any matching term and save them as a string.

For example, the following passage contains the word "Springfield." I need to capture the term Springfield, as well as the 20 characters surrounding it on either side, and save the entire excerpt as a string, *excerpt*.

> This is a sample passage that includes the term Springfield. The
>   sample passage goes on to describe the population, demographics and
>   tourist attractions in the community etc.

The result should be something like this:

> excerpt = "t includes the term Springfield. The sample passage"

Comment: Try this regex `.{20}Springfield.{20}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is close to what you are looking for, but you have not given all the rules. In particular you have not said what happens if `"Springfield"` is preceded or followed by fewer than 20 characters. (I've assumed at most 20.) Also, you haven't said whether `"Springfield"` can be part of a longer word. I've assumed it cannot, but just remove the word breaks (`\b`) from the regex if that's not the case. Also, I've `join`ed with `':'` just to show where the joins are, but you can of course change that to `''`.

```
def extract(str)
  str.scan(/.{,20}\bSpringfield\b.{,20}/).join(':')
end

extract(text)
  #=> "t includes the term Springfield. The sample passage" 
extract("a Springfield 123456789012345678 Springfield b")
  #=> "a Springfield 123456789012345678 :Springfield b" 
extract("a bSpringfield 123456789012345678 Springfield b")
  #=> " 123456789012345678 Springfield b"
```

If, in the second example, if you wish to show the (up to) 20 characters preceding the second `Springfield`, you can use a positive lookahead with the form of [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) that takes a block. Here the block variable `m` is an array containing the values of the two capture groups (i.e., `m => [$1,$2]`. Note that, when supplied with a block, `scan` returns the original string, so it's necessary to capture the results of the matches in an array (here `a`).

```
def extract(str)
  a = []
  str.scan(/(.{,20}\bSpringfield)\b(?=(.{,20}))/) { |m| a << m.join }
  a.join(':')
end

extract("a Springfield 123456789012345678 Springfield b")
  #=> "a Springfield 123456789012345678 : 123456789012345678 Springfield b"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text = "This is a sample passage that includes the term Springfield. The sample passage goes on to describe the population, demographics and tourist attractions in the community etc."

search = "Springfield"
i = text.index(search)    

excerpt = text[i-20..i+20+search.size]
# => "t includes the term Springfield. The sample passage "
```